# Lazy loading Spring Data JPA repositories

Tags: spring-data, spring-data-jpa

We have *lots* of repositories defined via the interface extends JpaRepository pattern. When running integration tests or certain entry points to our application, we only need a very small subset of those repositories.

Can we lazily load the actual repository implimentations?

Something equivalent to @Lazy on a @Bean? Note: I did at least attempt the naive solution of annotating the repository interface with @Lazy to no avail.

Answer (score 2):

Even if it's a very old Question, I think some may still want to know about the use of ***@Lazy*** on Spring Data repositories :

it is actually supported since [v1.5.0](https://jira.spring.io/browse/DATAJPA-419)

Comment: Is it still true to >v1.10.2? Because my repository is not being initialized lazily, even with the `@Lazy` annotation.

Answer (score 0):

Lazyloading will avoid to get all other dependency based on your main table or request. In your case you should set a limit / offset for that kind of operation.